# Issue with merging two data tables with uneven number of columns in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have initialized a data table below and other data table is "get_LR".

```
ryear_cols <- c("1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018")  


Tab <- setNames(data.table(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 28, c(ryear_cols))
Tab <- data.table(sapply(Tab, as.numeric))
Tab:
    1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

get_LR: 
Practice All_prac_pct 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001  2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008  2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
1:      763          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2:      320          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3:      702          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I need to merge these two tables and the output I want is shown below.

```
Output: 
Practice All_prac_pct 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001  2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008  2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
    763          100    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0    0    1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    320          100    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0    0    1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    702          100    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0    0    1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

How can I achieve this in R in data table method.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example input data

```
df <- structure(list(Practice = c(763L, 320L, 702L), All_prac_pct = c(100L, 
100L, 100L), `1997` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `1998` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `1999` = c(1105L, 1105L, 1105L), `2000` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `2001` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2002` = c(668.7, 668.7, 668.7), 
    `2003` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2004` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2005` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), `2006` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2007` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `2008` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2009` = c(164.8, 164.8, 164.8), 
    `2010` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2011` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2012` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), `2013` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2014` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `2015` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2016` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `2017` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L), `2018` = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df
#   Practice All_prac_pct 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001  2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
# 1      763          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
# 2      320          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
# 3      702          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
#   2007 2008  2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
# 1    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

**If input data is data.frame and not data.table**

Add new columns of NAs if the column doesn't exist

```
newcols <- setdiff(as.character(1991:2018), names(df))
df[newcols] <- NA

df
#   Practice All_prac_pct 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001  2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
# 1      763          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
# 2      320          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
# 3      702          100    0    0 1105    0    0 668.7    0    0    0    0
#   2007 2008  2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 1991 1992 1993
# 1    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   NA   NA   NA
# 2    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   NA   NA   NA
# 3    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   NA   NA   NA
#   1994 1995 1996
# 1   NA   NA   NA
# 2   NA   NA   NA
# 3   NA   NA   NA
```

Reorder columns

```
num_names <- as.numeric(names(df))
df <- df[order(!is.na(num_names), num_names)]

df
#   Practice All_prac_pct 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001
# 1      763          100   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    0 1105    0    0
# 2      320          100   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    0 1105    0    0
# 3      702          100   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0    0 1105    0    0
#    2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008  2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
# 1 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3 668.7    0    0    0    0    0    0 164.8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#   2017 2018
# 1    0    0
# 2    0    0
# 3    0    0
```

**If input is data.table**

```
newcols <- setdiff(as.character(1991:2018), names(df))
df[, (newcols) := NA]

num_names <- as.numeric(names(df))
setcolorder(df, order(!is.na(num_names), num_names))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the output I wanted.